# Changing mysql query_cache_limit without having root priviledges

Tags: mysql, cache, database

Can query_cache_limit in mysql 5 be set locally for a specific database? I don't have root privileges to change the global variable.

Can query_cache_limit be set locally for each database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can only be done by someone with root as you already understand.

But if it were me, I would check with them.  They may be able to give you a custom my.cnf file.

Comment: Are there any other caching options that I can enable instead without having root access ?